# Don't display the username when I user CakeDC/users plugin

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model-view-controller, orm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEVo6.png)

You can see that the plugin displays the user id instead of username. How can I resolve this.

The users in the controller:

```
$users = $this->Histories->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('history', 'companiesGrants', 'statuses', 'users', 'tags'));
```

And the using in the Template, in the .ctp file

```
echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setDisplayField()` method on a table object to configure the display field of a table:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setDisplayField('username');
    // Prior to 3.4.0
    $this->displayField('usernme');
}
```

or you can configure the fields used for the key and value with the `keyField` and `valueField` options respectively:

```
$users = $this->Histories->Users->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'username'
]);
```